# spring form submission in a popup

Tags: spring, forms, spring-mvc

I have a small problem in my first spring&hibernate application.

In my page, I would like to create a popup window (modal) which gives the possibility to send an email.  So, this popup would display a spring form with a fied "subject" and a field "content".

The question is : how can I use the form binding mechanism of spring with this popup form if I don't want my main page (displayed behind the popup form) to be reloaded?

If i am not wrong, the content of the popup is a div present in the main page.  So, If I submit the form in the popup, the whole page will be reloaded (through the mvc mechanism of spring) and this is exactly what I don't want.

Of course, I can submit my form via an ajax call to a spring controller, but in this case, how to handle the eventual errors in the form?  I cannot use the spring form binding mechanism to display the errors on the popupform.  Is it possible?

Do you know if there is a way to open a new window in a modal popup?  So that this page and only this page would be reloaded during the submission of the form?

Actually, I am not sure of the best way to combine a popup containing a form and the form submission mechanism of spring.  How to display the errors on the form in case of errors? after reload of the page, If there are some errors, I need to open my popup again in javascript and then display the errors on the popup, this is the only mean I see, but maybe there are easier solutions.

If you have, I would be happy to know it.

thanks a lot

Comment: Did you try popup created by javascript function showModelDialog which creates another window as modal popup. Look and feel might be impacted. But the validation problem should be resolved using this.

Comment: Or you can try ajax validation. Submitting form using ajax so that page will not be refreshed even if validation fails.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  I think that the method showModalDialog works only on internet explorer.  Concerning the ajax call validation, it is indeed the "less bad" solution, but by using this way, I loose some functionalities of the mvc mechanism of Spring (errors management).  But, anyway, I should be able to deal with that.

Comment: I would be interested with what solution you are taking as I may also have to deal with it in future.

Comment: http://spring.io/blog/2012/08/29/integrating-spring-mvc-with-jquery-for-validation-rules